# PhoneGap Build - Windows Key not in Select-Box

Tags: windows, cordova, build

I have a problem with Adobe's PhoneGap build. I only know not quite whether it is a problem with the service itself or my data.
With iOS, as well as Android, there are no problems, from debug to releas - everything is perfect.

Now I would like to release the Windows app as a release, but no key can be selected here. I have already tried several times to add the new key, also via the function 'add a key ...'.

As a label I tried some things (Package Family Name (PFN), Package / Identity / Name, Package / Properties / PublisherDisplayName etc.), but without success. If I do not mind right, that worked a week ago so far.

Screenshot:
[PhoneGap Build Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNQdL.jpg)

Does somebody has any idea?
Thanks in advance. :)

(Sorry for my bad English, I've already been translated by Google-Translator, but the whole is not perfect either :P)

Comment: Okay, i solved the problem myself: The App is for Windows 10-Devices, but Phonegap has not recognized ist, but the BuildBot already. Simply add via Edit account -> Signing Keys -> Windows 10 an self-signed pfx-certificate - Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I believe that from the version 6.0 of the phonegap it requires the creation of pfx to solve this and does not need to create the pfx certificate I added in the config.xml a downgrade of the version of the phonegap only to the windows phone for a smaller version and there it appeared The option to include the created id publisher worked like this:

```
<Platform name = "winphone">
<Icon src = "res / winphone / ApplicationIcon.png" width = "99" height = "99" />
<Icon src = "res / winphone / Background.png" width = "159" height = "159" />
<Preference name = "phonegap-version" value = "cli-5.4.1" />
</ Platform>
```